# get response from XMLDocument in web service in javascript Ajax call...?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, asmx, webmethod

i'm calling a .asmx web service from Server is is calling fine, it return response in XMLDocument and i need only result like TRUE or FALSE

service .cs file code is :

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string UserLogin(string u_name,string user_pwd)
    {
        string result = "true";
        if (u_name == "unicolumn" && user_pwd=="admin")
        {
            result = "true";
        }

    else
        {
            result = "false";

        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(result);
    }
```

my ajax call code is like this:

```
   function apiLogin()
    {
     var UserName = document.getElementById('txtUserName').value;
   var PWD = document.getElementById('txtUserPWD').value;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.200.56/ChatApp.asmx/UserLogin?u_name="+UserName +"&user_pwd="+PWD,
    datatype:"html/xml",
    success: function (xml) {


    //alert(xml.find("string").text());
    console.log(xml);
},

    failure: function(Response) {
        alert(Response.d);
    }
});

}
```

and the response of this ajax call is:

```
  <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">"true"</string>
```

and i want this is only as TRUE or FALSE , someone can help me to figure out what i'm missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Response.Write(). In your WebMethod:

```
if (u_name == "unicolumn" && user_pwd=="admin")
        {
            Response.Write("true");
        }

    else
        {
            Response.Write("false");

        }
```

Then, in the ajax call:

```
...
     success: function (xml) {
        if (xml.responseText == "false") { 
              (your code) 
       }
},
```

Comment: it is a web method in .asmx file so where i'm not able to write like this 

 Response.Write("true");